# unrar part of a multipart rar file

Tags: compression, application, rar

Suppose you have a multipart rar file, say `file.part1.rar`, `file.part2.rar`, `file.part3.rar`.

I know that I can extract only the first parts using for example

```
unrar e -kb file.part1.rar
```

However assume that I have only `file.part3.rar` and **not** part 1 and 2. Is then there a way to extract the content of part 3?

Is this possible if the rar file contains a video file? (Extracting part 3 schould then result in a video file which contains only the last x minutes).

If it is not possible, is it because it is in principle impossible or because there is currently just no program which can do it.

**Edit**: Is it possible to extract say the last part if you have just the last and the first part but not the parts between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to be impossible, cause multiparted rar archive contents metadata about all the files inside all the parts of an archive.

and even if you tries to unrar a single file (movie) not from the beginning, it will fail, cause file contains metadata of itself in the beginning, and even video stream is a container with a special format ant it's headers and so on... (mp4, mkv...).

Even if you'll try to chop the file, it's a bad idea. Just find a full source of the file you want ))